# WPF sync item position and size between two list view

Tags: wpf

I have two list view side by side that displaying the same data in different perspective.

Every time a data entry is added, I add an item in both ListView at the same index.

I want the same item in each ListView has the same height. But the MeasureOverride of them are called separately. How do I solve this?

===========================
Here's the example code .

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListBox Grid.Column="0" x:Name="leftList">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
    <ScrollViewer>
        <ListBox Grid.Column="1" x:Name="rightList">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Desc}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AddPerson(new Person() { Name = "Ali", Desc = "123A" });
        AddPerson(new Person() { Name = "Akram", Desc = "456X" });
        AddPerson(new Person() { Name = "Salman", Desc = "Very long description ........................................" });
    }

    void AddPerson(Person person)
    {
        leftList.Items.Add(person);
        rightList.Items.Add(person);
    }
}
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Desc { get; set; }
}
```

In the reality, the ListViewItem is more complicated, I must write custom controls for them.

In most case, the ListViewItem of the right list takes more space than that of the left list, but I need to keep them to have the same height.

I can't use Grid to do this because I need the content of the right ListView to be able to scroll horizontally.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Try adding items to a grid instead (with two columns)

Comment: @lsma Sorry, stack panel seems not fit for this, I should use Listbox instead. I wrote a sort code snippet to describe my question.

Answer (score 0):

Set the same styling (with static height) to whatever it is you add to your StackPanels.